# quickest way to annotate entity from database to given text in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, text

my database is

sport_type :  table

```
 id  type  
 12  Cricket
```

persons : table

```
id   name   details
1   person1  he is good in cricket
2   person2  he is a player
```

I am looking for way to identify persons in given text which are already stored in  my database example :

I am having text as

> Person1 is very good in Cricket. Person2 is friend of Person1

so when I submit sql query i should get results as

> **Person1** is very good in **Cricket**. **Person2** is friend of **Person1**

code should be able to identify the items or entities which are already stored in my database.

how should I achieve this with the help of python and mysql ?

Comment: You could split your text and get tokens for your text.
Then compare the list of tokens with the table in your database

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?